# How to leverage Java type conversion from Javascript running on a Rhino interpreter

Tags: javascript, java, type-conversion, rhino

I have a Rhino Javascript interpreter (specifically part of the Blocklauncher Android application, a mod platform for Minecraft).

Given that Javascript numerics are floating point and I wish to convert in both directions between an array of 8 bytes and 64 bit signed integers, 64-bit floating point numerics, 64 bit date/time values and UTF-8 text, is it possible to leverage Rhino's capability to execute Java code to perform these conversions and also to perform 64-bit signed integer math?

If so, how?

Since the Rhino JS interpreter is embedded in Blocklauncher, it is not possible for me to configure it in any way.  Any code must work as-is.

Comment: I'm confused by what you're trying to accomplish, can you show a code example in js and why that doesn't work? Anyways, in nashorn we can define a variable for a class instance in java, then call that class' methods in javascript. It sounds like you just want to make a bunch of helper methods in java that input a number and output a converted type.

Comment: @CausingUnderflowsEverywhere, I want to convert a byte array of length 8 to and from the following: a 64-bit signed integer, a 64-bit floating point numeric, a date/time value and UTF-8 text.  As Javascript uses only 64-bit floating point numerics, they cannot handle Int64 values or math.  I want to be able to leverage Rhino's ability to execute Java to have Java do the work of conversion and integer math where necessary.  So, yes, I want Java helpers in Rhino javascript.